# Can I delete one of my posts that has been closed as off topic and received an answer with positive up-vote?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Can I delete one of my posts that has been closed as off topic and received an answer with positive up-vote?

Should I delete all my posts that has been closed as off topic? (with/out answer)

Comment: To my knowledge, questions which have an upvoted answer cannot be deleted unilaterally. And in general it is also not a good idea to delete too many questions, in order not to risk a question ban. While the exact rules are not public, a rough rule of thumb is that a question which has been downvoted, closed and deleted is much worse than a question with which only one of these has happened, and still a bit worse than one with which two of these things have happened.

Comment: I reckon you should *improve* all your posts that have been closed as off-topic.

Comment: Details about deletions can be found in the network-wide FAQ: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) You cannot delete your question if it has multiple answers or if it has an upvoted or accepted answer, is a duplicate target or an answer got a bounty. Other users can still vote to delete your question, even in such situations. (But only users with sufficient reputation.)